# Write a function that calculates an operation result given 2 numbers and the operator

Tags: python

I have tried this, but the problem is I don't know how to make the function identify math operations like `+` or `-`

```
def calc(n1,n2,"x"):
    y= n1 x n2
    return y
```

Comment: What is the method supposed to do? Describe it with a few words and maybe provide some input and expected output.

Comment: In Python you use * for multiplication (n1 * n2). Also, you might need: ** for powers (e.g. 2**3 = 2^3 = 8). Finally, remember in Python 2 division is integer division, so you might want to convert denominator to float

Comment: Why can't the user type the calculation itself? Even when dealing with custom objects you should define the corresponding `__add__`, `__mul__` (and so on) methods instead of tinkering something manually in that function.

Comment: @a_guest "Why can't the user type the calculation itself?" => perhaps the OP is writing a calculator program where the user enters some formulas in a GUI ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `operator.*` and a map:

```
import operator

operators = {"+": operator.add,
             "-": operator.sub,
             "*": operator.mul,
             "/": operator.div}

def calc(n1, n2, op):
    return operators[op](n1, n2)
```

---

**Addendum:**

Note that I initially only wrote those four operators, but with this approach any two-number-operation can be easily added (remainder, boolean operations...). More *ad hoc* operations can be added by implementing the function, like:

```
import random
import operator

def dice_thrower(n_dice, dice_size):
    return sum(random.randint(1, dice_size)
               for _ in range(n_dice))

operators = {"+": operator.add,
             "-": operator.sub,
             "*": operator.mul,
             "/": operator.div,
             "d": dice_thrower}
...
# unchanged `calc` function
```

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions:

Solution #1 : do a test on your 'operator' value:

```
if operator == '+':
    return n1 + n2
elif operator == '-':
    return n1 - n2
# etc
```

Solution #2: Python functions are objects so you can build an 'operator=> function" dict (using `lambda` makes it even easier):

```
OPERATIONS = {
    "+" : lambda n1, n2 : n1 + n2,
    "-" : lambda n1, n2 : n1 - n2,
    "*" : lambda n1, n2 : n1 * n2,
    "/" : lambda n1, n2 : n1 / n2,
    }

def calc(n1,n n2, operator):
    return OPERATIONS[operator](n1, n2)
```

Solution #3: do the same thing using the `operator` module that already provides operators as functions:

```
import operator

OPERATIONS = {
    "+" : operator.add,
    "-" : operator.sub,
    "*" : operator.mul,
    "/" : operator.div,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `eval`:

```
def calc(n1,n2,operator):
    return eval(str(n1)+operator+str(n2))
```

result:

```
 calc(2,5,"-")
 >>-3
```

Comment: _Don't_ use `eval()` (unless you _really_ know what you're doing and even then) -  it's unsafe, makes code hard to debug, and is 99.99 times out of 100 useless because there's a better way.

Comment: for this kind of super simple function I don't see a problem with using `eval`.

Comment: I want the function to do any given operation, for example, input, (2,3,*) output 6, or input (2,3,+) output 5

Comment: @Riko you may explicitly state what do you mean for "any given operation" in the original question. That is not an intuitive and trivial definition.

Comment: @Riko - what I wrote will work for the operations you stated.

Comment: @beniev it's not a problem of complexity, it's a problem of teaching the right solutions (cf my answer) instead of the unsafe ones. `eval()` _is_ unsafe, makes code harder to debug, and there __is__ a better (and canonical) solution (here the `operator` module and a mapping).

Answer (score 0):

The safest, although not the most convenient solution is to define a function that does the work "by hand":

```
def calculate(num1,num2,sign):
    if sign == "+":
        return num1 + num2
    elif sign == "-":
        return num1 - num2
    elif sign == "*":
        return num1 * num2 #multiplication
    elif sign == "**":
        return num1 ** num2 #powers
    elif sign == "/" or sign == ":":
        return float(num1) / float(num2) #division
    elif sign == "%":
        return num1 % num2
    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid operator in use') # handling invalid signs
```

Usage: `print(calculate(3,2,"*")) # prints 6`

I really prefer this solution, because you can perform custom operations and you can add as many as you want. For invalid signs, this throws an `Exception`.

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: In Python we have exceptions that are used to signal errors, invalid conditions etc. Your function should raise an exception in the `else` clause instead of returning a special value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @brunodesthuilliers. I have edited the answer

Comment: @mr-xcoder this is better but a more specific exception would help - a custom subclass of `ValueError` would be the right choice here - so the caller can handle it differently than say a `ZeroDivisionError` or a `ValueError` raised by passing invalid `num1` or `num2` values.